# iOS disable animation for NavigationController back button

Tags: ios, swift, navigationcontroller

I want to disable the animation when i pop a ViewController with the back button in NavigationController.

I tried:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(false)
}
```

But it still animates.

Answer (score 5):

In the Controller that you want to have that button:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: .Plain, target: self, action: #selector(backTapped))
}

@objc func backTapped(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(false)
}
```

Take into account that this way, you will lose the < icon on the back button (since you're overriding that button). However, I think it is not possible to have a custom behaviour and the < icon at the same time (unless you add the < icon as an image by yourself)

Comment: Then i don't get the < icon.

Comment: That is right. I don't know if it is possible with the < icon. I'll keep trying ;)

Comment: You're overriding the default button, you cant keep the arrow, you have to in that case add the arrow as an image for the new button.

Comment: Exactly, in the solution I provided you override the button, son you lose the < icon. That's right. See the edited answer

Comment: This syntax changed a bit with Swift 3/4. Essentially you need to change the argument in your action to `#selector(backTapped)` and  add `@objc` before your function declaration. 

src: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39205613/selector-syntax-for-swift-3-0

Answer (score 3):

In which ViewController you don't want animation,
Add below lines

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
}
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
}
```

Comment: This solution does works, but if you present your view (or navigation) controller modally, this will break the drag to dismiss animation. `viewWillDisappear` is called when you begin the drag to dismiss gesture, even if you ultimately back out of it.

Answer (score 1):

Just Use this on the viewcontroller you have to pop

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(false)
    UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
}
```

Or

```
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(false)
    UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
}
```

Animation for view is totally removed. And After poped don't forget to add `UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)` on your next viewcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

`viewWillDisappear()` doesnt handle the animation, its just.

If you're using a `UINavigationController`

```
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: false)
```

If you're just using `UIViewController`

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to custom animation maybe try this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "◁", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(backTapped(sender:)))

}
```

// with fade animations

```
@objc func backTapped(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let transition: CATransition = CATransition()
    transition.duration = 0.5
    transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeIn)
    transition.type = CATransitionType.fade
    self.navigationController!.view.layer.add(transition, forKey: nil)
    navigationController?.popViewController(animated: false)
  }
```

// "◁" added this way: Edit -> Emoji & Symbols

Answer (score -4):

You can try this

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?popViewControllerAnimated(false)
}
```