# Selector syntax for swift 3.0

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3, uibutton

I am trying to add target into button this way:

```
btnAll.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

But it is giving me an error:

> Use of unresolved identifier 'buttonTapped'

But I declared function like:

```
func buttonTapped(sender: UIButton) {

    print("All Tapped")
}
```

Can anybody tell me what is the correct way to do this in swift 3.

Comment: Show us your buttonTapped method. IBAction methods can have 0, 1, or 2 parameters depending on how you set them up, and we can't know what form you used.

Answer (score 84):

Add target like,

should now be written as `#selector(buttonTapped(sender:))` or use `#selector(buttonTapped(_:))`

```
btnAll.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

then change your function like,

```
@objc func buttonTapped(_ sender : UIButton){

 ....
 }
```

Comment: This is what I have already answered.. :)

Comment: It changes function to @objc

Comment: Sorry, i mean, in protocol extensions it needed to change the function to @objc

Answer (score 23):

You can do it this way:

```
btnAll.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```