# Unrecognised selector sent to instance within custom UICollectionView button

Tags: ios, swift

I have a custom `UICollectionViewCell` with a button called `collectionViewButton` inside the cells.

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionViewCell


    cell.collectionViewButton.tag = indexPath.item
    cell.collectionViewButton.addTarget(self, action:#selector(CollectionViewController.collectionButtonAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    ...

}
```

which calls the function:

```
func collectionButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton){
    ...
}
```

When the button is pressed the error:

> '[ProjectName.CustomCollectionViewCell collectionButtonAction:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance' appears.

`CustomCollectionViewCell` code:

```
class CustomCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var collectionViewButton: UIButton!

}
```

Comment: A pattern I often use (which will let you easily associate the button press with the cell and associated data), is to declare a closure inside the cell, such as `var onButtonPress: ((Void) -> Void)?`. Then, in the cell class, I'd add the `collectionButtonAction` function (and add it as the button's target action) and call `onButtonPress` within it.
Finally, in `cellForItemAt`, I'd simply assign a closure to `cell.onButtonPress` and do whatever I want to do when the button is pressed.

Comment: What is the complete and exact error message? You left out all of the import parts of the message.

Comment: I'll edit the post now

Comment: What is the name of the class which implements the collection view data source? it probable that the name is not **CollectionViewController** as you have used in `#selector(CollectionViewController.collectionButtonAction(_:))`. Try to use just `#selector(collectionButtonAction:)` . [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39205650/2604204)

Comment: Changing the code to that throws the same error

Answer (score 0):

Add one target for your `collectionViewButton` in cell initialisation method and call closure in property, like:

```
class CustomCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionViewButton: UIButton!
    var actionHandler: (() -> Void)?

    init() {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        collectionViewButton.addTarget(self, action:#selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func buttonAction() {
        actionHandler?()
    }
}
```

Set needed handler in `cellForItemAt` method of collection view delegate.

Answer (score 0):

Change this below line

```
cell.collectionViewButton.addTarget(self, action:#selector(CollectionViewController.collectionButtonAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

to

```
cell.collectionViewButton.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.collectionButtonAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

try this once.

Comment: something is missing. if you have some extra code show it once. or the complete error message.