# Disable animation with backBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

As my title saying is there any way to customize default back button action method ?

I tried to find on Google but not get any answer that fulfill my requirement.

I know one way to Add `UIBarButtonItem` to `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem` and customize action method but I will be hide **<** sign of **Back** button and I don't want this.

Some R&D that done by Google.

1) [How to override self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem Action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30522230/how-to-override-self-navigationitem-backbarbuttonitem-action)

2) [iOS disable animation for NavigationController back button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33542009/ios-disable-animation-for-navigationcontroller-back-button)

3) [Google Question/Answer](https://www.google.co.in/search?rlz=1C5CHFA_enIN748IN748&q=self.navigationitem.backbarbuttonitem+.action+animation+false&oq=self.navigationitem.backbarbuttonitem+.action+animation+false&gs_l=psy-ab.3...1639.1639.0.1894.1.1.0.0.0.0.191.191.0j1.1.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0.XwdKgZpoTKI)

Add image that look like `<Back` button that is one way but I want to going with native way.

Comment: what is your expected output? elaborate your question properly.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to implement the viewWillDisappear method on the View Controller and set animationEnable No

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated : Bool) {
super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
   UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
} 
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
      UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
}
```

Comment: Will not be helped because I just want to disable animation of moving and viewWillDisappear method call when moving is started

Comment: But it will disable animation for all the screens of the App so We need to manage True for all relevant screens

Answer (score 0):

you have to add your custom bar button there...

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
         let button = UIButton(frame: YourDesiredFrame)
        button.setImage(UIImage(named : "back"), for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(backButtonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
        self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = barButton
}


    func backButtonTapped(_ sender : UIButton) {
        _ = self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated : false)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Swift 4
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
    // turn on animations
    UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    // turn off animations
    UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
}
```